# Run-time error when using ExportAsFixedFormat

Tags: vba, macos, ms-word

I get the following error:

> Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)':
>
> Method 'ExportAsFixedFormat2' of object '_Document' failed

I cannot figure out why the error occurs. See below for the entirety of my code.

```
Sub ExportAsPDF()
    ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat2 OutputFileName:="test.pdf", ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateHeadingBookmarks
End Sub
```

The file name is just a test. I've tried using the full path where I want to save it to: /Users/tom/Downloads/test.pdf (no such file already exists at this path).

Comment: Have you tried turning on the macro recorder, exporting it manually, stopping the macro recorder, and then looking at the code it created?

Comment: Hmm - no repro in Word 365, but on Windows - I see you're on Mac. Does this fail in a blank, new document?

Comment: @bigben Yes, it fails on a new doc.

Comment: I'm guessing this will fail as well, but what if you drop the `2` and use `ExportAsFixedFormat`?

Comment: I confirm the issue using `ExportAsFixedFormat` on the Mac (VBA has no `ExportAsFixedFormat2` method). What does work for me is `ActiveDocument.SaveAs2`, specifying a PDF file name and the `wdSaveFormatPDF`.

Comment: dropping the 2 does not work. ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 doesn't save bookmarks like exportasfixedformat does. Also, here is the documentation for ExportAsFixedFormat2: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.exportasfixedformat2

Comment: Thanks for the link - I'm not seeing the method in Office 365 VBA listing... Don't forget to "ping" people using @TomJ or we won't see any replies in comments. It looks like this is a bug in VBA on the Mac. From my researches a few days ago, it appears to have something to do with the Mac "sandboxing" - where one is allowed or not allowed to save files, whether path and filesnames are correct. My *guess* would be that Microsoft did not implement it completely/correctly for Mac VBA.

Comment: @Cindy, @Tom, putting and/or saving files to the "UBF8T3346G9.Office" folder (sandboxing workaround) does not help. I can also confirm that both `ExportAsFixedFormat` and `ExportAsFixedFormat2` fail the same way.

Answer (score 0):

I've got exactly the same problem and i've found the solution.
the path is too long, which makes the function crash.

Try to copy your file on a smaller path aand retry

Comment: How much shorter could I possibly make the path?