# How to export PDFs automatically on MAC?

Tags: vba, macos, ms-word

We work in a team. Some of us on PC, others on MAC.

I came up with this sub for exporting PDFs automatically (+ linked to Excel via publiposting for the naming), which works on my PC but it won't work on MAC.

```vb
Sub Export_nom_lot_pdf()
'
' Export_nom_lot_pdf Macro
'
'
Dim UpDir As String
UpDir = ActiveDocument.Path
AwKN = ActiveDocument.Name
SplitAwKN = Split(AwKN, ".")
NomFichier = SplitAwKN(0)
SplitNF = Split(NomFichier, "_")
phase_nom = SplitNF(0)
lot_num = ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.DataFields(8).Value
lot_nom = ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.DataFields(9).Value
entreprise_nom = ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.DataFields(13).Value
'
ChangeFileOpenDirectory UpDir
ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:=phase_nom & "_lot-" & lot_num & "_" & lot_nom & "_" & entreprise_nom, ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord = wdNextRecord
End Sub
```

Comment: [*"It's not working"* is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)
we need a good error description.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

You do not say where your error occurs, but the one thing in your code that will almost certainly not work is the call to `ExportAsFixedFormat`.

If so, this question is arguably a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57517108/run-time-error-when-using-exportasfixedformat) i.e. that neither `ExportAsFixedFormat` nor `ExportAsFixedFormat2` seem to work on Mac. The situation does not seem to have changed since then. You can use `SaveAs2` instead, e.g.

```
ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 _
  OutputFileName:=phase_nom & "_lot-" & lot_num & "_" & lot_nom & "_" & entreprise_nom, _
  FileFormat:=WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF
```

That will not allow you to use some of the options that are available when using `ExportAsFixedFormat`.

There are some other things in your code that could cause problems or might cause problems on Windows if you change to using `SaveAs2`, e.g.

- If the ActiveDocument has not been saved, `UpDir` will be `""`, and that will cause an error in `ChangeFileOpenDirectory`.
- It is possible that there are special characters in the file name that are allowed on Windows but not on Mac
- You might need to add the extension ".pdf" to the name. (I do not think it is actually needed but you should check).

If you need to use different code on the Windows and Mac versions, you can use "directives" to do it, e.g.

```
#If Mac Then
' put code for the Mac version here
#Else
' put code for all other versions here
#End If
```

See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/ifthenelse-directive) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/compiler-constants) for more information on that.

At one time the main way to create PDFs from software on Mac was to print to that format. The current version of Mac Word also has User Interface options equivalent to the ones in Windows Word (e.g. the option that sends the file to a Microsoft Service for conversion. So I switched on the VBA Macro Recorder and recorded that. But it didn't record anything.

Just my opinion, but if you need to write code that works on both Windows and Mac, you really need to have both types of system available to you. Microsoft's own documentation for the Office object models is primarily based on the Windows version and there are a lot of differences - sometimes quite minor, such as a an object property that's on Windows but not Mac, sometimes larger, such as objects that are not implemented on Mac, and sometimes the more confusing situation where something just works differently on the two platforms.

(Sorry,if you post comments I can't reply to them yet).