# Setting 'Tagged PDF' to 'Yes' when saving a Word doc as PDF on Mac OS - is it possible in VBA

Tags: vba, macos, pdf, ms-word, tagged-pdf

I'd like to save a Word doc as PDF on Mac. 'Tagged PDF' should be set 'Yes'. I can do this manually, but I'd like to do this in VBA. Do you have any idea how to achieve this whilst neither ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat nor ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat2 is not working on Mac ?

Thanks for your ideas if you have any...

I checked some issues [How to export PDFs automatically on MAC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72867745/how-to-export-pdfs-automatically-on-mac?rq=3) and [Run-time error when using ExportAsFixedFormat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57517108/run-time-error-when-using-exportasfixedformat))

Comment: You have already found the answer in the posts you linked to in your question.

Comment: Thanks for checking my question. I re-read those posts, but I'm still helpless. As I can see Save2 does not have the property to set 'Tagged PDF'. The second solution, printing the document as PDF does not give me the chance to set any property in the output neither.

Comment: Without ExportAsFixedFormat/ExportAsFixedFormat2, (which AFAICS are still not implemented on the Mac version) AFAICS the only way to achieve this would be to use Mac GUI Scripting, which means that you would have to do *at least* the following: allow GUI scripting in the user's Mac System Settings, if you can, put a file containing the necessary AppleScript code in the correct place in the Library container for the Microsoft Word application, and call it from VBA using AppleScriptTask. Then support all that. Can't say I think it's a good idea!